# Sharing folders with VirtualBox, Windows 7 Host and Ubuntu 9.10 Guest

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a development setup from this tutorial: [Build Your Own Dev Server with VirtualBox](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/10/27/build-your-own-dev-server-with-VirtualBox/).

But what I can't figure out is how to share a folder on my Ubuntu virtualized machine with the host Windows 7. I want to use a Windows text editor to edit code that's on my Ubuntu server.

I've tried using the Shared Folders setting, adding "/var/www" but it says that the path is not absolute. When I click on "other", it only allows me to browse folders on my Windows 7 host.

Both the host and guest are 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 5):

Install the **Guest Additions** for the guest OS and configure the shared folder(s) on the host OS. You'll find these options in the **Devices** menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of trouble with this, but found a pretty easy workaround.  It involved setting up a second network adaptor for the guest os.  Have 2 adaptors on system:  1> NAT and 2>Host-Only Adapter connected to VirtualBox Host only network adaptor (this was selected from dropdown list).
This allows two things...1 maintains connection to the internet for updates, etc., and 2 allows guest to be visible on workgroup in win7 host OS.  Now you can share folders from the guest OS to windows =>since I couldn't get it to work the other way around.  This was useful for me as I rarely transport things from vista to ubuntu anyway.  With mindterm installed on Windows and an openssh-server installed on the guest OS, I was then able to enable two-way file tranfers between win7 and ubuntu, which was really ideal, using the SFTP plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your perfect solution with just "NAT".

Quoted verbatim from http://blogs.oracle.com/tao/entry/virtual_box_shared_folder_between:

> 1. Add folder(s) to shared folder menu.
>
>    It is important to write down the folder names at this step.
> 2. Boot guest system, open a terminal and type in the following commands
>
>    ```
>    sudo mkdir /mnt/tao_xp
>    sudo mount.vboxsf TAO /mnt/tao_xp
>    ```
>
> The shared folder would be accessible now: read & write!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was switching my "Network Adapter" in VirtualBox from "NAT" to "Bridged".  This can be done in VirtualBox's menu, "Devices" -> "Network Adapters".  All of this needs to be done after installing "Guest Editions".  For some reason, my install defaulted to "NAT", which I never could get to see my networked computers.